# How can I access and view the Samsung Internet cache?

Tags: cache

I'd like to try and recover a lost website that might have been cached on a Samsung Internet browser, where would the cache be located? I'm running Android 11. I've checked in Phone\Android\data, but there doesn't seem to be a correlating folder for Samsung Internet.

Answer (score 1):

[Samsung Internet browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.app.sbrowser&hl=en_US&gl=US)'s package name is `com.sec.android.app.sbrowser`. You should check the cache files under the folder `/data/data/com.sec.android.app.sbrowser`. Note that you need root access to read that folder.

Comment: As the Samsung Internet browser app defines `allowBackup="false"` the alternative way via `adb backup` also doesn't work. Directly accessing the data directory with root permissions is the only way.